# Config IIS 8 server mapping handler

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, iis, static-files

I ran my servlet in Tomcat 8 and served some static files in IIS 8.

My servlet can be reached via http://localhost/myServlet/...
and static files could be retrieved via http://localhost/...

I have the following setting in my IIS configuration.

```
 <add name="BonCode-Tomcat-WC-Handler" path="/myServlet/*" verb="*" type="BonCodeIIS.BonCodeCallHandler" 
      resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="integratedMode" />
 <add name="BonCode-Tomcat-JSP-Handler" path="*.jsp" verb="*" 
      type="BonCodeIIS.BonCodeCallHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

However, there are some static files staying in the servlet.

If I place the image directly under servlet, 
I am able to access static files via this link: http://localhost/myServlet/myImage.jpg.

If I place the image in a subfolder call "images" (The folder path should look like [servelt]/images/myImage.jpg), I am not able to access static files via this link: http://localhost/myServlet/images/myImage.jpg.

If I add `path="/myServlet/*/*"` to the configuration like this:

```
<add name="BonCode-Tomcat-WC-Handler" path="/myServlet/*/*" verb="*" type="BonCodeIIS.BonCodeCallHandler" 
      resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Then I am able to access static files via this link: http://localhost/myServlet/images/myImage.jpg.

So my questions are:

- Why `"/myServlet/*"` doesn't include this case `"/myServlet/*/*"` ?
- If I have some static files in deeper sub folders such as
  http://localhost/myServlet/images/smallsize/myImage.jpg, then I have
  to add another configuration `path="/myServlet/*/*/*"` ? I guess
  there should be better way to handler this.

Comment: For IIS 8 and above you should consider Microsoft HttpPlatformHandler over other third party components.

Comment: @LexLi I tried to use HttpPlatformHandler  but I couldn't make it work. I am not sure if HttpPlatformHandler does the same thing as what I wanted. I followed this linke: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-release-of-the-httpplatformhandler-module-for-iis-8/ but it doesn't work. Resource in IIS server cannot be accessed. Tomcat app refuse connection.